# if appending divs with getJSON, is it possible to display them animated one at a time?

Tags: jquery, json, append, jquery-animate

Hey everybody.I'm appending some divs through a getJSON function but i want to jazz it up a bit. Right now all the divs are displaying at the same time. Is it possible to display them milliseconds apart? Like the first fades in, then the second, and so on?

Here's what I have right now for example:

```
$.each(result, function(i, field){
  $(".thumbnail_area").append(  
    "<div class='thumb_container'>....</div>"
    ).children().css('background-color', 'red').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
  });// of result function
});// of foreach function
```

As of now, everything fades out after a second. (oh btw i know i said i wanted them to fade in, but im just using fadeOut bc its easier to test the effect)

thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index value you've already got in the loop (`i`) to generate a delay that increases with each iteration.

```
$.each(result, function(i, field){
  $(".thumbnail_area").append(  
    "<div class='thumb_container'>....</div>"
    ).children().css('background-color', 'red').delay(1000 * i).fadeIn(1000);
  });// of result function
});// of foreach function
```

Each item will be delayed `i * 1000` milliseconds, so they'll fade in 1000 milliseconds apart from each other.

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply the delay by `i` in your function.

```
$.each(result, function(i, field){
  $(".thumbnail_area").append(  
    "<div class='thumb_container'>....</div>"
    ).children().css('background-color', 'red').delay(1000*i).fadeOut(1000);
  });// of result function
});// of foreach function
```

Check working example i did before for a simiar question http://jsfiddle.net/Xc6jn/3/

Comment: Or, you could do something like (100*i-100) so each div fades *out* 100 milliseconds apart, with no delay after the call is returned. (unless i starts at 0, then just ignore me)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
 setInterval(function() {   
    $('<div>').html('Hello!').addClass('blah').hide().appendTo('#container')
    .fadeIn(2000);
 }, 2000);
```

Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/QpWLs/1/